# Круглый график с текстом снаружи

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, canvas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу создать подобный график. Нашел библиотеку chart js, однако там нет возможности добавить текст снаружи. Текст должен двигаться вместе со шкалой.

Буду благодарен за любую информацию ( статью, видео, пример кода ) !!

Comment: Попробуйте https://amazing-react-charts.vercel.app/donut-chart#demo

Comment: спасибо большое!